# Input "submit" inside textarea not clickable in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a simple form that allows users to send mails to the site's owner. I wouldn't like to change it totally, because I've got already written PHP script for this, and this solution worked fine before I tried to add some styles to it...

The problem is, "Wyślij >" (submit) inside the textarea does not work ONLY in firefox. I can't click it, like the button is somewhere underneath. In Opera, Chrome, Edge, IE - it works just fine. I'm starting to giving up on this. I would appreciate any help, I don't know what's causing this.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c0vz64m1/

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="kontakt.php" id="contactform" style="margin-left:35vw; margin-top:20px;">
            <label for="name">Imię<font color="white">*</font>:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder=" Twoje imię (wymagane)" required /><br>

            <label for="email">Email<font color="white">*</font>:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder=" Twój email (wymagane)" required />

            <div id="text-area">
            <label for="message">Wiadomość<font color="white">*</font>:</label><br>
            <textarea name="message" rows="9" cols="50" id="message" placeholder=" Twoja wiadomość (wymagane)" equired></textarea>


            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Wyślij &raquo;" class="submit-button"/></div>
        </form>
```

CSS:

```
    input#name,input#email {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px skyblue;
    border:2px solid skyblue;
    border-radius:7px;
    padding-left:5px;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}

input#name:focus,input#email:focus {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px skyblue;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}

input#name:hover,input#email:hover {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px skyblue;
}

.submit-button {
    width:75px;
    height:36px;
    margin-left:380px;
    display:block;
    margin-top:-41px;
    border-top:2px solid blue;
    z-index:5000;
    font-size:14pt;
    color:skyblue;
    font-family:Andada;
}

textarea {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px skyblue;
    border:2px solid skyblue;
    border-radius:10px;
    resize:none;
    height:150px;
    width:375px;
    z-index:1;
    padding-right:75px;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}

textarea:focus {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px skyblue;
    transition:all .2s ease-in-out;
}

textarea:hover {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 20px skyblue;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute positioning to put the button over the textarea and it will work.

Remove from class `.submit-button` these things:

```
margin-left:380px;
margin-top:-41px;
```

and add these:

```
position:absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: 30px;
```

Then add `position:relative` to `#text-area` .

Comment: It fixed one of the issues. But then, the second one appeared.

http://jsfiddle.net/w86o8hhh/2/ try to resize the frame and you'll see this: http://take.ms/KIytM

It's like it does not want to place this button where it should be.

EDIT: nevermind. I'm apparently tired and I've forgot to place the position:relative; for #text-area. Sad thing, it stands in place when I resize the page horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Please see updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w86o8hhh/ which adds:

```
  z-index:10;
```

to the CSS, and:

```
  id="submit"
```

to the submit button